# MySQL get row ids of affected rows and update them again after update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-event

Basically I'm updating my `orders` table and modifying the status if the date is older than x amount. What I want to do is get the affected rows and insert a row into my `events` table to record the event and my events table recognize its orders by a `order_id` field which should be the same as the `order_id` in the `orders` table.

So down to some code.

```
UPDATE `orders` SET `status`='7' WHERE `date` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 172800) AND `status` = '2';
```

The rows that this query updates has to go through some for each loop to insert a row for each affected row into my `events` table. Some how I have to get the `order_id` to use in this query:

```
INSERT INTO `orders_events` (`order_id`, `event_id`, `user`, `date`) VALUES (12345678, 6, "Admin", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()))
```

I was figuring to first `select` the orders and `insert` them into a `temporary table` and `modify` them there and then `select` them again to get the row id's and `insert` the `event` data from the rows in the `temporary table`. However i ran into a problem here since i have no idea how to get the rows and `insert` into the events with a kind of for each loop in mysql.

What would be the proper and most efficient way of doing this in a stored procedure / mysql scheduled event?

*Also I'd like to add, Locking the table is a no go since its being updated by multiple users every* minute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it!

```
INSERT INTO `orders_events` (`order_id`, `event_id`, `user`, `date`) 
SELECT id, 6, 'Admin', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) FROM `orders` WHERE `date` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 172800) AND `status` = '2';

UPDATE `orders` SET `status`='7' WHERE `date` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 172800) AND `status` = '2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the information you are looking for

```
$affected = mysql_info();
//this will let you see what is returned
echo '<pre>'; print_r($affected); die();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php

However, you will notice that it is being deprecated. If you aren't already using PDO or Mysqli you should look into doing so.  Here is the Mysqli equivalent of the above http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php

Comment: Sorry but I don't use php... I'm using a stored mysql event procedure. No php used at all.